# Check a folder for new files in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to check a folder for new files in the last 24h. I wrote this little Script but it doesnt work so well.

```
$folder = 'C:\Users\XMAN\Desktop\Unfug\'
$filter = '*'
$date = (Get-Date).addDays(-1)
     if (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName}| Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime} -gt $date){
        Write-Host $._FullName -fore green
    }else{
        Write-Host "I have nothing to do."
    }
```

I know you have some ideas. :D

Grázias!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question and explain why it doesn't work so well, and what you're trying to accomplish in more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your pipeline is wrong:

```
$newFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -Force -File |
    Where-Object CreationTime -gt $date |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

if ($newFiles)
{
    foreach ($file in $newFiles)
    {
        Write-Host $file -ForegroundColor Green
        ...
```

You were removing the property from your object before filtering on it.  Also, you're filtering on `LastWriteTime` which will not be accurate if you're looking for *new* files, so I'm filtering on `CreationTime` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
if (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName} |...)
```

That line only returns file paths and sends a list of strings down the pipeline. So you took an object, grabbed one property (fullname), then passed it to where-object and checked for a ModifiedDate which no longer exists.

You likely want something like this to accomplish this:

```
$folder = 'C:\ps-files\ClaimRedrop'
$filter = '*'
$date = (Get-Date).addDays(-1)
#Check if files exist outside of if statement. This is better for readability
$FileCheck = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -Force | 
    Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt $date}

if ($FileCheck){
    # Avoid using Write-Host where possible. Whenever possible write to output or default
    $FileCheck | ForEach-Object {Write-Output $._FullName}
}
else{
    Write-Output "I have nothing to do."
}
```

Comment: Line 10 edit:
From:  $FileCheck | ForEach-Object {Write-Output $._FullName}
To: $FileCheck | ForEach-Object {Write-Output $_.FullName}

Just a typo on the underscore.